# Telegram API, содержимое файла

Tags: python, telegram

Как сделать так, чтобы бот отправлял содержимое определённого файла? Использую python. Пытаюсь считать построчно содержимое файла в переменную и отправлять значение этой переменной, но не работает.

Comment: Добавьте код с ошибкой

Comment: Что не работает? Какой у Вас код? Что вы используете? Укажите в вопросе, иначе пойдут минусы.

Comment: никаких ошибок не выводит, просто не отправляет сообщение. пробовал выводить в консоль - всё работает